# Does synchronization takes such long time for first time or every time when syncing?

Tags: synchronization, time, bandwidth

My internet bandwidth is around **10 - 20 KB/s**. If I could sync with it for the **first time** then no problem. If I should need to **sync it every time** when opening it then it's really a big problem for me.

Comment: Are you sure this is no problem?  By my estimate, syncing the entire block chain will take about 30 days of continuous transfer at that rate.

Comment: Yes you are correct! It is a problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial sync only needs to happen once, launches after a full synchronization will just catch up on the data that you've missed.